# HiddenFieldFor not working for controls rendered conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On my view I have some fields which are rendered conditionally. The fields are nullable booleans so I am using 'EditorFor()' with custom editor template for boolean (if this is important)

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HasAccount, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.HasAccount)
    </div>
</div>
<hr class="dotted" />

@if (Model.HasAccount2)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ExtraField, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ExtraField)
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="dotted" />
}

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ExtraField)

<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Options, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
     <div class="col-sm-9">
         <div class="input-group">
             @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OptionID, Model.OptionsSelectList, "Choose an Option", new { @class = "form-control chosen-select" })
          </div>
     </div>
</div>


$('#Options').change(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ProcessOptions", "Home")',
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#ProcessForm').serialize(),
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("error");
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#divContainer').html(result.ViewString);
            }
        });
    });
```

Now when the View is posted then according to some condition in the controller I set the value of `ExtraField` to true or false. The controls for `ExtraField` will not be rendered unless the value for `HasAccount2` is true so to store the value I use the `HiddenFor()` for `ExtraField` so that when the form is posted again then `ExtraField` is passed as true and not null because it is not rendered.

Now the `HiddenFor()` does not have any value which is returned from the model. How can I store the value for `ExtraField` as hidden in this scenario?

**Edit**
There is a dropdownlist on the view. The view is posted using JQuery Ajax when the select index of dropdownlist is changed. The model is passed to the controller and processed and the partial view is returned with model as Json. Below is the controller method,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessOptions(MyOptions model)
    {
        if (model.OptionID == 1)
        {
            model.HasAccount2= true;
        }
        else if (model.OptionID == 3)
        {
            model.ExtraField = true;
        }

        return Json(this.RenderPartialViewToString("_Options", model););
    }
```

The method RenderPartialViewToString is just converting the PartialView as string. It all works fine except the ExtraField. Now as you can see that based on some condition I am rendering ExtraField when HasAccount2 is set to true so that User can select true or false by himself but incase OptionID is 3 then I don't want the ExtraField checkbox to be rendered rather I want to set it explicitly from controller and store it in HiddenField so that when user submit the form for save then the ExtraField value is also passed.

Comment: What do you mean by _"when the View is posted ... I set the value of ExtraField"_? Are you trying to update a value in the controller and return the view? If so show your controller methods.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Kindly see my edited question. I hope that it is clear now.

Comment: Your ajax method is called when an element with `id="Options" is changed, but you don't have an element with that id (only a `<select>` with `id="OptionID"`). Is that a typo? And what is the reason for your `RenderPartialViewToString()` method and returning a `JsonResult` as opposed to returning a partial view?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Yes this is a typo. The View is pretty big so I mentioned the important parts by manually typing here. RenderPartialViewToString is not a problem as it is due to the approach I am using. I was fairly new to MVC so for returning PartialView to the success method of Jquery Ajax I started returning partial view by returning it as string.

Comment: But what is the point of returning it as a `string`? If `_Options` is a partial view then just use `return PartialView("_Options", model);` and in the success callback `$('#divContainer').html(result);`.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I was using this earlier for another purpose and started using the same for current scenario. It is not a problem. Thanks for this advice.